# vb.net 2010 Excel Border Style

Tags: excel, vb.net

I cant seem to find a border style I need.  There seem to be fewer available than on excel itself.  I want a line above and double below similar to a total of numbers added up on column of numbers.  For accounting purposes.

```
 excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
```

or

```
excel.XLbordersIndex.
```

There only seem to be minimal options

The format i would like is as follows (similar to:

"-------------"

========

The both borders is should be continuous however

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Quite a long time ago that I played around the last time with VBA

I think something like the following is what you're looking for:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim range As range
    Set range = Worksheets(1).range("B2")

    With range.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThick 'Optionally set a weight
        .ColorIndex = 23  'or a color
    End With

    With range.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
    End With
End Sub
```